# Show that this sum is the length of an interval I

Tags: analytic-number-theory

**Problem**

We have an interval $ I \subseteq [0, 1) $ and the indicator function defined as $ \chi_I(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } x \in I\\ 0 \text{ if } x \not \in I \end{cases} $

What we want to show is if the following is true
$$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n + 1} \sum_{k = 0}^n \chi_I(k \alpha \mod 1) = |I| $$

where $\alpha$ is an irrational number such that $0 < \alpha < 1$ and  $ |I| $ is the length of the interval.

**Solution**

So my first approach was that I tried to convince myself this numerically using Python. I did the following for some different lengths of the interval:

Suppose that $I = [a, b] \subseteq [0, 1)$ then the length of the interval is calculated as $|I| = b - a$. The sum $\sum_{k = 0}^n \chi_I(k \alpha \mod 1)$ can be written as 
$$ d_{k + 1} = d_k + \chi_I(k \alpha \mod 1) $$ 
where $k = 0, 1, ..., n$. Now, for some arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ we can pick an index $N > 0$ and we get that

$$|\frac{1}{n + 1}d_{n + 1} - |I| | < \varepsilon, \forall n \ge N $$

This means that the sequence $ \frac{1}{n + 1}d_{n + 1} \rightarrow |I| $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

But I'm still stuck because I don't know how to prove this analytically. For the interval $(0, 1)$ we get that
$$
\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n + 1}\sum_{k = 0}^n \chi_{(0, 1)}(k \alpha \mod 1) = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n + 1}(\underbrace{0 + 1 + ... + 1}_{= n}) = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \underbrace{\frac{n}{n + 1}}_{< 1} = 1
$$

Since the length of the interval $(0, 1)$ is just $1$. But how do I show this for any $I = [a, b] \in [0, 1)$ such that 
$$|I| = b - a = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n + 1} \sum_{k = 0}^n \chi_{[a, b]}(k \alpha \mod 1)?$$

Comment: What you want to prove is equidistribution of the fractional parts of $n\alpha$ in $[0, 1]$. That's technically difficult, but as you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Equidistribution_modulo_1), there's Weyl's criterion, and that's very easy to check in this case.

Comment: Thanks again, Vector! I think this solved my problem. I managed to show, for some irrational $\alpha$, that the sequence of real numbers $(n \alpha) = \{0, \alpha, 2 \alpha, 3\alpha, ...\}$ is uniformly distributed over $[a, b] \subseteq [0, 1]$. Hence, the sum above is equal to $ (b - a) / (1 - 0) = b - a = |I| $ by the definition of equidistribution in that wiki-link you gave me.